# Loading cert file on application start

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to load a cert file when the application starts to use later for crypto validation. I do not want to read this file every time I invoke the function I am using its contents in, what is the best way to load this file once and use multiple times?

Comment: Don't forget about specifying `@external_resource`: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-external_resource
Looks like you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up solving the problem by using a GenServer with the key loaded in its init function and stored in its state.